# Powershell: IF, TRY and CATCH block in powershell script

Tags: powershell, if-statement, signtool

I am using try and catch block inside IF condition, but I am not getting the desired results.

```
If (Test-Path -Path "$env:DigiCertificate"){

try {
    signtool sign /f $env:DigiCertificate /v /t http://timestamp.sectigo.com /a /fd SHA256 /p $env:DigicertsPassword $MediaFolderPath\scripts\*.ps1 $MediaFolderPath\tools\*.exe
}catch
{
    Write-Host "required certificate not found to sign" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Write-Host "$($_.Exception.Message)." -ForegroundColor Red
    exit 1
}
}
```

In the above code I am expecting the `IF condition` should check for the `-Path` and it should fail if it does not find the **DigiCertificate**. Apart from try and catch block even IF condition should work, but I am trying to do it but I am missing something.

Comment: If the path does not exist, it will not execute any part of the try statement, i.e. the catch part will also not be executed. Is that what you intend?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, if the `-Path` is not correct or the certificate is not available at the location, it should fail saying **required certificate not found**

Comment: For that to work, you would need to put the `Write-Host "required certificate not found to sign" -ForegroundColor Yellow` line in the `else` part: [Everything you wanted to know about the if statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-7.2#alternate-execution-path).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks for the immediate response. So you are telling that I need to add the `else` part after the `try and catch` block? coz I am looking for something first it should check for `-Path` and then it should also check for `signtool` command execution successful or not, if not for that also it should fail.

Comment: If you're saying what I think you're saying, then yes. Give it a go!

Comment: @AndrewMorton Sorry, I have tried it but not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us what your code looks like now, so we can be sure.

Comment: `try` / `catch` most likely won't work with an external executable, you want to use `$LastExitCode` assuming the executable returns proper exit codes or redirect stderr to stdout in powershell `2>&1` then see if the object is an `ErrorRecord` or not

Comment: signtool does not throw terminating exception so try/catch will not work the way you want it to.  Instead take out the try/catch, run your signtool line and on the next like check for success with `if (-not $?) { error handling }`

Comment: @Daniel
  Thanks for the suggestion, definetely it helped me alot to resolve it.